# display value from jSON object

Tags: javascript

I apologize ahead of time - I'm new to this! This is a function to retrieve a JSON object:

```
var testButton = document.getElementById('testButton');
var text = document.getElementById('Text');

testButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    var getUser = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var URL = "http://location/folder/testuser.json";

    getUser.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (getUser.readyState == 4 && getUser.status == 200) {
        text.innerHTML = getUser.responseText;
    }
  };
  getUser.open("GET", URL, true);
  getUser.send();
});
```

This is the JSON object:

```
 {          
    "dateofbirth":"01/02/2016",
    "email":"DonaldDuck@email.com",
    "firstname":"Donald",
    "lastname":"Duck",
    "password":"mypassword"
 }
```

The function displays the entire json object, which is expected. How would I display just the dateofbirth, email, firstname, etc? Thanks!

Comment: JSON stands for **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation, and is a string, not an object. Use `JSON.parse(getUser.responseText)` to convert it from a string to an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference each property with `.propertyname`, so to display the name:

```
text.innerHTML = getUser.responseText;
```

becomes:

```
text.innerHTML = getUser.responseText.firstname + ' ' + getUser.responseText.lastname;
```

Comment: This was the correct way to do it, but for anyone else looking through this in the future, I had to use var parsed = JSON.parse(getUser.responseText); first and then refer to each as parsed.firstname + ' ' parsed.lastname

Answer (score 1):

`objectname.item` like `objectname.dateofbirth`

Answer (score 1):

You could store the response data in a Javascript object like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(getUser.responseText);
```

Then you can access each of the key-value pairs like any Javascript object like so:

```
text.innerHTML = json["dateofbirth"]; // Alternatively: json.dateofbirth;
```

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects are accessed directly by key,so you can write easily `obj.propname`